# Trouble plotting with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I apologize, once again, if this has already been posted and discussed, but this is the output I'm getting from my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "photometry_V1283_Her.py", line 28, in <module>
    plt.scatter(xcoord,ycoord)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2550, in scatter
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 701, in gca
    ax =  gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 369, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 343, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 80, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1712, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I'm running Xming on my Windows computer, using PuTTY to run the code on my server. Here is my code:

```
import scipy.ndimage as snd
import pyfits
import aplpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a1 = pyfits.open('final_processed1.fit')

Image_1 = a1[0].data

Image_1 = Image_1.reshape(Image_1.shape[2:])

threshold = Image_1.mean() + 2*Image_1.std()

print threshold

labels, num = snd.label(Image_1 > threshold, np.ones((3,3)))

centers = snd.center_of_mass(Image_1, labels, range(1, num + 1))

print centers

xcoord = [a[0] for a in centers]
ycoord = [a[1] for a in centers]

print xcoord,ycoord

plt.scatter(xcoord,ycoord)
plt.savefig('star_positions_V1283_Her.jpg')
```

It finds all of the star positions in an image, in this case, an image of V1283 Her, a variable star I'm studying. I want to plot the output from this code, which is printed as such:

```
[5.4528163019450888, 76.484683060846763, 96.25283577429451, 133.0, 164.82650590142723, 169.8320261305239, 177.98832604084942, 233.28232143914147, 239.0, 258.17815256468492, 257.02193435130732, 260.50503209293748, 261.02212680561541, 265.0, 279.0, 293.99894094320223, 297.0, 306.0, 330.60227293401715, 347.0, 409.0, 412.45866606520525, 431.01612522746746, 440.0, 457.0, 460.0, 461.83741684760963, 508.58063037685065]
```

as the x-coordinates, and

```
[423.51536446140085, 757.97957285998814, 535.94001057710625, 641.0, 183.74640134087025, 264.83875681244996, 550.34113141774742, 265.81037713985006, 165.0, 375.58603732999728, 406.96129416111245, 76.0, 478.12486839424827, 458.0, 673.4953061140526, 508.99336986804775, 51.528063913624557, 327.0, 746.62083264590092, 347.93356549524702, 346.0, 327.13278979301151, 106.62161219292472, 345.0, 157.0, 578.0, 58.855805168101405, 459.94512381829935]
```

as the y-coordinates.

Hope you guys will help,
Brandon

Comment: The error seems pretty straightforward. Is XMing running? Did you remember to use the X-forwarding on your system when connecting? Is X-forwarding setup on the remote server?

Comment: I'm looking into it...apparently it's nothing to do with Python, but the way in which my setup is. I'm looking through forums, such as here: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-778860.html to see if I can't get it to work.

Comment: I edited files, nothing seems to be working...now I'm getting this error: couldn't connect to display "localhost:10.0"

Comment: What about in Putty? Did you set X-Forwarding? You should also try to restart the XMing server, as the default display is actually: "localhost:0.0".

Comment: @jrd1 Yes, I set X11 forwarding in PuTTY, went and made sure it was enabled on my Debian server as well. I'll try restarting XMing.

Comment: I have had the similar issue and the problem was that I had accidentally set the display manually to some value (eg. localhost:5.0). Make sure you allow Xming to set your display, if you don't know how to, it is better to reinstall Xming which will have default settings